# Kaggle problem for dogs and cats with kernal using ANN is not working for me

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have written Artificial Neural network code to solve Keggale Dog and Cats Kernal problem but somehow during training, it shows loss=nan and bad accuracy. My code can be found at https://www.kaggle.com/dilipkumar2k6/dogs-vs-cats-with-new-kernel/notebook

Following are details on error

```
from tensorflow import keras
# First apply Artificial neural network (ANN)
ann = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)), # Flaten 3d to 1d
    keras.layers.Dense(3000, activation='relu'), # more hidden layer gives better perf
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'), # more hidden layer gives better perf
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'), # more hidden layer gives better perf
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')    
])
ann.compile(optimizer='SGD', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
ann.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=10)
```

Error

```
Epoch 1/10
438/438 [==============================] - 2s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 5.0000e-04
Epoch 2/10
438/438 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: You use Gradient Descent optimizer. As I know this optimizer can go to the reverse direction that optimum, when training vectors and learning rate are too big(big numbers to big moving, that might be too much, next move would be even bigger, because weight become bigger and so on.

Usually this issue are solved using normalization, I see you apply basic normalization already.

So you can change normalization strategy, or play with learning rate. That might help without changing the model

Comment: I tried to use Adam, it started printing loss, but accuracy was very poor close to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `sigmoid` activation function in your output layer seems a bit strange to me when using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` (although it could also work). Anyway, I think you should consider changing this line:

```py
keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
```

to

```py
keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

and use `tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()`.
Or change your activation function to `softmax` and leave the rest as it is.

You should also consider redesigning your model and using at least one `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` layer before flattening the data. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

ds, ds_info = tfds.load('cats_vs_dogs', split='train', with_info=True)

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)

def resize_inputs(data):
  images, labels = data['image'], data['label']
  images = tf.image.resize(normalization_layer(images),[64, 64], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
  return images, labels

ds = ds.map(resize_inputs).batch(64)

ann = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), # Flaten 3d to 1d
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'), # more hidden layer gives better perf
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'), # more hidden layer gives better perf
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'), # more hidden layer gives better perf
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')    
])
ann.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), metrics=['accuracy'])
ann.fit(ds, epochs=10)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
364/364 [==============================] - 58s 140ms/step - loss: 0.8692 - accuracy: 0.5902
Epoch 2/10
364/364 [==============================] - 51s 141ms/step - loss: 0.6155 - accuracy: 0.6559
Epoch 3/10
364/364 [==============================] - 51s 141ms/step - loss: 0.5708 - accuracy: 0.7009
Epoch 4/10
364/364 [==============================] - 51s 140ms/step - loss: 0.5447 - accuracy: 0.7262
...
```

You can experiment with this example and find out which combination of activation function, loss function, and number of output nodes works best for you.

Comment: Thx for highlighting the issue in the loss function. The rest of the code was ok. Also, in your sample, you have used a convolution neural network. I was first trying with the artificial neural network.